# In javafx 2 when editable set to true ,onKeyPressed, OnKeyTyped are not calling Combobox?? Please guide me

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, dropdownbox, javafx-webengine

Actually We need editable dropdown.so that we have made changes that setedtitable(true) and added StringConvertor.But KeyPressed and Keytyped previouly working for filter when it is not true.but now it's not calling. can anyone help me how to avoid that ? filter is not working due to keyPressed is not calling....

Answer (score 2):

The way I handled this was to get the TextEditor of ComboBox and add onKeyTyped event.

Note: TextEditor is returned if the ComboBox is set to editable.

Example:

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class AddDataController  implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> groupName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {            
        groupName.setEditable(true);
        TextField tf = groupName.getEditor();
        tf.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                // To Do
            }

        });
    }
}
```